# Big theta of function with multiple types of n

Tags: asymptotics

I have the following function:

$\displaystyle\frac{n \cdot 7^n+\frac{8}{n!}}{(n+7) \cdot 7^n}=\Theta(1)$

I don't how they come to this. What is the proper way to analyse a function to theta notation?

Answer (score 5):

You can calculate the limit of the function for $n\to\infty$:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\cdot7^n+\frac{8}{n!}}{(n+7)\cdot7^n}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\cdot7^n}{(n+7)\cdot7^n}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{8}{n!}}{(n+7)\cdot7^n}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+7}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{8}{(n+7)\cdot7^n\cdot n!}\\
&=1 + 0\\
&=\Theta(1)
\end{align}

Comment: Note that this was the extra lucky case that there was a limit. Big-theta doesn’t require a limit, but it makes things easier.  To OP: What happens if we multiply the whole lot by (2 + cos n)?

Comment: i guess it is not possible in big theta notation?  Could you tell me what the general way is of analyzing a function to big theta notation?

Comment: The general way consists of reading the definition of big-theta and thinking hard about the problem at hand. Read the definition of big-theta and my example problem becomes very easy.